# C# WPF application freezed over time

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, tcp, kinect

I have built a C# WPF application that has several background threads which are doing the following tasks:

1. several threads where each contains a TCP server running in a while loop and each of them is just waiting for a message from a specific port
2. One thread is constantly monitoring a USB port for an I/O device
3. One thread is acquiring data from a Microsoft Kinect device
4. Some timer dispatcher thread doing some updating based on "flags" (or static global variable) raised from other thread.

An example of:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Server));
    private static void Server()
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.119");
            // use local m/c IP address, and 
            // use the same in the client

            /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8003);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("The server is running at port 8003...");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("The local End point is  :" +
                              myList.LocalEndpoint);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Waiting for a connection.....");

            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            k = s.Receive(b);
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");

            string temp = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
                temp += Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
            }

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("\nSent Acknowledgement");
            /* clean up */
            s.Close();
            myList.Stop();

            if (k > 0)
            {
                cont = true;
                k = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }    
    }
```

So the problem I have encountered is that occasionally the application just freezes up and I can not access it at all. The main UI thread also freezes up, and I can not kill the program even from task manager in windows. Normally the application runs perfectly fine, but the problem will appear randomly after using the application for long hours (e.g. for 4~5 hours)

The computer I am using is not a high-end PC with only 2G RAM and AMD dual core CPU.

My guess of the problem can be as following:

1. Insufficient memory (or memory leak somewhere, but windows is working fine and only the program freezes)
2. Network jam (i.e. deadlock somewhere, but this doesn't seem likely with simple send and receive application)
3. Failed to established connection with USB devices (including kinect)

However, I am still not sure how to figure out the problem. I might be still quite new to the implementation, so I would love to hear comments from some experts in C# WPF, networking and multi-threading applications to help me out here. Thanks.

Comment: if you are able to use .net 4 or 4.5, i'd suggest looking into Task Parallelism: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx  It provides an option for long runnning threads

Comment: while loop?  What while loop?  Also, why many servers on different ports?   Servers are not normally designed like that - usually, there is only one listening thread on one port and then one client<>server thread per connection.

Comment: If your app is dying after 4-5 hours, try checking how many sockets are stuck in TIME_WAIT with netstat.

Comment: To go along with @MartinJames, also take a look at Duplex binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

Comment: @MartinJames, I forgot to put an example of the while loop in the above code, but basically it is more like having several publisher/subscriber application at several ports for different information exchange between computers within an intranet. Some of them will just be waiting for one connection and some will be constantly monitoring a port (i.e. where the while loop comes into place). I will look into those suggestion you have mentioned, especially the next time the same problem appears. Thanks for the help, I will report back any testing outcomes soon.

Comment: that's a hell lot of thing that the application is doing

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug this is to attach a debugger (Visual Studio can do this). Then look at what the threads are doing. To use VS to debug go to Debug -> Attach To Process and select your process. If that doesn't work, you can try to dump the process using task manager (if you have Windows 7 or above), just right click the process and select Create Dump file. Then you can do an offline analysis of the file using windbg or VS. The most useful you'll want to look at is what the threads are doing when it's locked up. These are normally the best first steps for this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio  is a [concurrency visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx)

I would use that (I think its aviable since VS 2010. This can also be attached to an external process ( like Visual Studio Debugger also can.

Also you could consider using tools like the [Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) from redgate